# Dos modelos en un solo template Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hola de antemano gracias por leerme, a continuación tratare de explicar a detalle mi problema, estoy desarrollando una app donde tengo dos modelos, un que se llama Producto y otro que se llama TamañoPrecio el cual tiene una relación con el modelo Producto de ForeignKey, yo hice un CRUD para el modelo Producto, y mi intención era que luego de crear un producto, me redireccionará a un DetailView() de una instancia del modelo Producto, luego ahi poder crear una instancia para el modelo TamañoPrecio en un mismo template, para eso cree un createView para el segundo modelo "TamañoPrecio" y puse como template de esta vista el template que se genera para el detailview del modelo Producto, bueno el problema es que yo al incluir mi formulario en ese template me da un error con el models que pase en ese template porque al parece me da una especie de conflicto al pasar dos vistas con distintos models a un template (ya he pasado dos vistas mismo template pero con modelos iguales y no he tenido problemas, por eso creo que el conflicto yace en que django no permite hacer lo de pasar dos modelos o, bueno esto supongo yo)

ok ahora pasara las partes del código para que entiendan un poco mas mi problema. Este es mi models.py

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estas son mis dos vistas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y acá mi formulario adentro del template de la vista generada por el detail
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien tiene información acerca de como pasar solucionar esto o simplemente me quiere aportar algo estoy abierto a opiniones

gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu DetailView, agrega un sistema que valide ese formulario.

**Aqui un ejemplo**

```
def post(self, request):
    form = Tuforms(data=request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        variable_del_formulario= request.POST.get('variable')
        mi_modelo = Producto.objects.all()
        mi_modelo.variable= variable_del_formulario
        mi_modelo.save()
        msg_txt = """
            <p>Contenido agregado</p>
        """
        messages.success(request, msg_txt)

        return redirect ('nombre_de_url')
```

**Nota:** Es mejor que agregues el código y no pongas imágenes